# Accessing Properties Outside the context of a gridview

Tags: xaml, uwp

In an attempt to learn UWP I decided to (try and) build a simple card game.  I have the following XAML to present the cards on the UI:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <vm:HoldemVM x:Name="viewModel"/>
</Page.Resources>

<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind holdemVM.Players}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Player">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width= "92"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="260"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <localControls:PlayingCardControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                        CardHeight="{Binding viewModel.CardHeight }" 
                                        CardWidth="{Binding viewModel.CardWidth}"
                                        CardValue="{x:Bind Hand[0].CardValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        CardSuitValue="{x:Bind Hand[0].CardSuitValue, Mode=OneWay}">
                </localControls:PlayingCardControl>

                <localControls:PlayingCardControl Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"
                                        CardHeight="{Binding viewModel.CardHeight }" 
                                        CardWidth="{Binding viewModel.CardWidth}"
                                        CardValue="{x:Bind Hand[1].CardValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        CardSuitValue="{x:Bind Hand[1].CardSuitValue, Mode=OneWay}">
                </localControls:PlayingCardControl>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView
```

As you can see my user control has a CardWidth and CardHeight dependency property that I would like to set via properties contained within the ViewModel.  The viewModel also contains  an observable collection called Players in which I am extracting the card and suit values depending on the cards dealt to the player.
Problem is I can't bind to the CardWidth/Height properties since my grid view has it's source set to the Players observable collection of which CardWidth/Height  are not a part of.
The XAML listed above renders the cards as expected with the exception of card width/height not being getting the changed properties from the viewmodel.
I have searched the net extensively and have tried a number of suggested options to no avail.  Hopefully someone out there can help me figure this out.
Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I  got a solution from another site.

Change the source to a StaticResource in the binding as follows:

```
<localControls:PlayingCardControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        CardHeight="{Binding CardHeight, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}" 
                        CardWidth="{Binding CardWidth, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"
                        CardValue="{x:Bind Hand[0].CardValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                        CardSuitValue="{x:Bind Hand[0].CardSuitValue, Mode=OneWay}">
</localControls:PlayingCardControl>
```

Thanks for your time..